# ArcGIS Pro - Maintaining Resolution in 3D Vertical Exaggeration - Animated Flyover

Tags: arcgis-pro, 3d, animation, vertical

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.0 (Local Scene) to make 30 second animated 3D flyovers of various subsea regions along the NA continental shelf.

I am encountering an issue with resolution/topography fluctuating with zoom, seemingly related to the vertical exaggeration function. The flyover plan is to fly in from a distance, pan, and zoom back out - looks epic, but the topography is quite visibly adjusting and optimizing with scale changes, somewhat ruining the effect. I'm curious if there is a way to rectify this, either through locking the dynamic adjustment in order to keep things stable OR through some other process or workaround that I'm not seeing?

Current elevation surface is a bathymetric GeoTIFF (GEBCO), exaggerated by a factor of 15 to better illustrate a 1km drop.